# Iterate through two keys in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm looking forward to iterating through both my keys here(models and dealers) and recording that in a csv. Maybe because i'm new to py or the way i'm used to like in sql, i'm not quite getting the idea of looping through two keys and getting the data. currently i'm doing a basic loop to extract the data, Any insight on how to address this would be really helpful

My code:

```
for x in data['models']:
   for y in data['models'][x]:
       fetch={'brand': x, 'model':y}
       resul.append(fetch)

for a in data['dealers']:
   for b in data['dealers'][a]:
       fetch={'brand': a, 'dealer':b}
```

My input:

```
data={ 
 "models" : 
       {
          "ford" : [ "ranger","mustang","ecosport","ikon"],
        "nissan" : ["gt","terrano"],
        "tesla" : ["cyber truck","model x","model s","model s2"],
        "honda" : ["civic", "accord"]
        },
    
 "dealers":
        {
         "tesla": [ "california", "newyork", "ohio"],
         "ford" : ["new jersey","hongkong","beijing","delhi","telaviv","ottawa"],
         "gm" : ["new york","washington dc"],
         "nissan" : ["dubai","saudi arabia"]
         }
}
```

Output:

```
| brand | models | dealers|
|-------|--------|---------|
|ford   | ranger | new jery|
|ford   | mustang| hongkong |
|ford   | ecosport| beijing |
|ford   | ikon    | delhi|
|ford   |         | telaviv |
|ford   |         | ottawa |
|nissan | gt      | dubai |
|nissan | terrano | saudi arabia|
|tesla  |cyber truck| california|
|tesla  | model x   | newyork   |
|tesla  | model s   | ohio      |
|tesla  | model s2  |           |
|honda  | civic     |           |
|honda  | accord    |           |
|gm     | new york  |           |
|gm     | washington dc|        |
```

Comment: I have the ability to extract the data using the for i've written but i was thinking if there's an elegant way were i can combine models and dealers data in one csv. right now i create two reports one for model and one for dealers.

Comment: Are you certain in advance that the models and dealers match up by order? As in, is the fourth entry in `data['dealers']` always guaranteed to match the fourth entry in `data['models']`?

Comment: Mostly Yes! The idea is to group them together like in my output to have a side by side view for better interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

As you have tagged the question with `pandas` here is one possible approach that significantly involve lots of `pandas` operations including `stack`, `explode` and reshaping using `unstack`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).stack().explode().to_frame()
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount(), append=True)[0]\
       .unstack(level=1).droplevel(1).rename_axis('brand').reset_index()
```

---

```
print(df)

     brand        dealers       models
0     ford     new jersey       ranger
1     ford       hongkong      mustang
2     ford        beijing     ecosport
3     ford          delhi         ikon
4     ford        telaviv          NaN
5     ford         ottawa          NaN
6       gm       new york          NaN
7       gm  washington dc          NaN
8    honda            NaN        civic
9    honda            NaN       accord
10  nissan          dubai           gt
11  nissan   saudi arabia      terrano
12   tesla     california  cyber truck
13   tesla        newyork      model x
14   tesla           ohio      model s
15   tesla            NaN     model s2
```

Comment: Hi Shubham! thanks for checking , but is this solution sustainable?

Comment: @lavanya_satheesh I suppose so. Are you expecting something else?

Comment: I've always been skeptical of using pandas. thought a for loop would finish the matter!! I will try and let you know :-)

Comment: @lavanya_satheesh Sure. Give it a try.

Comment: awesome, I went down the same direction ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple refactoring will suffice.

```
for key in ['models', 'dealers']:
    for x in data[key]:
        for y in data[key][x]:
            fetch = {'brand': x, key: y}
            result.append(fetch)
```

This works because the structure of both values is the same, only the name of the key mapped to them differs.

Comment: the problem with this is that you lose the original index

Comment: hey.thanks for dropping in. i'm yet to try this but i noticed here that we are having just two fields on the output ie the brand and the key. I would be needing three fields brand | model | dealers

Answer (score 0):

```
for key,value in data.items():
    if key=='models':
        for brand,model_list in value.items():
            for model in model_list:
                fetch={'brand': brand, 'model':model}
                resul.append(fetch)
                continue
    elif key=='dealers':
        for brand,dealer_list in value.items():
            for dealer in model_list:
                fetch={'brand': brand, 'dealer':dealer}
                resul.append(fetch)
                continue
    else:
        print("no brand available")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Syed !! I think, the dealers info are getting stuffed inside one line like this ['a','b','c'] instead. I think we may need to add another iteration to fix that. correct?

Answer (score 0):

There may exist a prettier solution, but this works.

```py
data={ 
 "models" : 
       {
          "ford" : [ "ranger","mustang","ecosport","ikon"],
        "nissan" : ["gt","terrano"],
        "tesla" : ["cyber truck","model x","model s","model s2"],
        "honda" : ["civic", "accord"]
        },
    
 "dealers":
        {
         "tesla": [ "california", "newyork", "ohio"],
         "ford" : ["new jersey","hongkong","beijing","delhi","telaviv","ottawa"],
         "gm" : ["new york","washington dc"],
         "nissan" : ["dubai","saudi arabia"]
         }
}

keys = list(data["models"].keys()) + list(data["dealers"].keys())
keys = set(keys)
def pad_lists(key,a,b):
    if a is None:
        a = []
    if b is None:
        b = []
    if len(a)>len(b):
        b += [None for i in range(len(a)-len(b))]
    elif len(a)<len(b):
        a += [None for i in range(len(b)-len(a))]
    key_list = [key]*len(a)    
    return key_list,a,b
    
df_brands = []
df_models = []
df_dealers = []
for key in keys:
    brands,a,b = pad_lists(key,
                           data['models'].get(key),
                           data['dealers'].get(key)
                          )
    df_brands.extend(brands)
    df_models.extend(a)
    df_dealers.extend(b)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"brands":df_brands,"models":df_models,"dealers":df_dealers})\
        .fillna('')
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>brands</th>
      <th>models</th>
      <th>dealers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>ford</td>
      <td>ranger</td>
      <td>new jersey</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>ford</td>
      <td>mustang</td>
      <td>hongkong</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>ford</td>
      <td>ecosport</td>
      <td>beijing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>ford</td>
      <td>ikon</td>
      <td>delhi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>ford</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>telaviv</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>ford</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>ottawa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>tesla</td>
      <td>cyber truck</td>
      <td>california</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>7</th>
      <td>tesla</td>
      <td>model x</td>
      <td>newyork</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>tesla</td>
      <td>model s</td>
      <td>ohio</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>9</th>
      <td>tesla</td>
      <td>model s2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>10</th>
      <td>honda</td>
      <td>civic</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>11</th>
      <td>honda</td>
      <td>accord</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>12</th>
      <td>gm</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>new york</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>13</th>
      <td>gm</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>washington dc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>14</th>
      <td>nissan</td>
      <td>gt</td>
      <td>dubai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>15</th>
      <td>nissan</td>
      <td>terrano</td>
      <td>saudi arabia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```